# creating folders in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I need to check if a directory exists, and if not then create it.  I know how to do this in .NET, but I am struggling with how to do this in classic ASP.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the following snippet. Make sure you have write permission before executing the code.

```
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If  Not filesys.FolderExists("c:\website\") Then      
  filesys.CreateFolder ("c:\website\")   
End If
```

Comment: This works when you only need the last folder in your directory to be created.  If you need several new folders in a directory to be created, you need to create them 1 at a time.